# Code from github clone doesn't search in right local repository and ModuleNotFoundError on MacOS

Tags: python

Very basic question. I am completely new to github and I see that similar questions have been asked but they don't seem to solve my problem.

I have tried downloading the following github repository https://github.com/chrsmrrs/k-gnn (I only want the code working locally on my machine). I used `git clone https://github.com/chrsmrrs/k-gnn.git` to download the contents of the github repository on locally so I can run some other code for which this package is necessary. I then went through the installation steps of this github repository and ran `python setup.py install` in the root directory of the git clone I made. When I tried to test the code, I typed in the following in command line as suggested in the github repo:

```
cd examples
python 1-2-3-proteins.py
```

However I get the following response from the command line terminal on my mac.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tom/Documents/300. MASTERS/MASTERS/THESIS/CODE/k-gnn/examples/1-2-3-proteins.py", line 18, in <module>
    from k_gnn import DataLoader, GraphConv, avg_pool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'k_gnn'
```

However, as far as I understand my sys.path is not looking for the module `k_gnn` as I did the following experiment

```
print(type(sys.path))
i = 1
for path in sys.path:
    print(i)
    print(path)
    i += 1
```

and got the following response

```
1
/Users/Tom/Documents/300. MASTERS/MASTERS/THESIS/CODE/k-gnn/examples
2
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/gnn-test-env/lib/python39.zip
3
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/gnn-test-env/lib/python3.9
4
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/gnn-test-env/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
5
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/gnn-test-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

As you can see it does search in `/Users/Tom/Documents/300. MASTERS/MASTERS/THESIS/CODE/k-gnn/examples` but not in `/Users/Tom/Documents/300. MASTERS/MASTERS/THESIS/CODE/k-gnn` where `k-gnn` is located. Is this due to my faulty download of the git repository or is this a fault of the code? If it's the former any help/reading material would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help and let me know if anything is unclear.

KR,
Tom

Comment: Have you tried opening an issue against that repo?

Comment: @JohnGordon I have not, don't know what the etiquette is regarding opening issues, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is any etiquette.  You're having a real problem; I can't imagine anyone being offended by seeing an issue about it.  However I see that the last commit was two years ago, so the author might not be paying attention anymore...

Comment: That's what I feared too. Will try to raise an issue.

Comment: Did you go through all the steps for installing pytorch_geometric?

Comment: yes I have installed all those. So both pytorch and pytorch_geometric. I have tried installing the 1.4 version however it was impossible trying to install 1.4 version of pytorch geometric. I tried to install an old version of python, an old version of pytorch (both succesful) but then installing an older version of pyg didn't work.

Comment: The [tag:git] and [tag:github] usage messages mention: "DO NOT USE the [github] tag for Git-related issues simply because a repository happens to be hosted on GitHub. Also, do not use this [git] tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository." Meanwhile, in Python terms, you're probably best off setting up a virtualenv for this, and/or forking the repository and doing your own updates to bring them into the modern Python world.

Comment: Thanks @torek for the examplanation on how to use the git and github tag. I have solved the problem now. The owner of the project has updates the package. best, Tom